# Issues running Direct X & Playing Games

Tags: gaming, steam, directx

Recently built a new computer, and I've never been more frustrated trying to figure out why games won't launch Via steam - there is an issue with Direct X Runtime.

Namely, I think I've isolated the issue that DirectX is failing to install and I can't figure out why.

I've tried a Fresh Windows 11 install, admin running, updating drivers, Sysregdata changing to 08 08 00 00 00 09 09 00 00 00, formatting my drives, running in compatibility mode, etc.  Not really sure what else to try, and I'm at my wits end.

Here is a copy of the DXError Note. If anybody has any potential fixes, I'm all ears.

```
--------------------
[07/03/23 12:03:11] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 2234, function: RegisterDLL

    Failed API:     LoadLibraryEx()
    Error:      (126) - The specified module could not be found.


    Unable to load C:\WINDOWS\system32\xactengine2_0.dll.

--------------------
[07/03/23 12:03:11] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 5861, function: DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn

    RegisterDllFromSection() failed.

--------------------
[07/03/23 12:03:11] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 280, function: CSetup::InstallPlugIn

    DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[07/03/23 12:03:11] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: setup.cpp, line: 1727, function: CSetup::SetupForDirectX

    InstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[07/03/23 12:04:53] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 2234, function: RegisterDLL

    Failed API:     LoadLibraryEx()
    Error:      (126) - The specified module could not be found.


    Unable to load C:\WINDOWS\system32\xactengine2_0.dll.

--------------------
[07/03/23 12:04:53] module: dxupdate(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 5861, function: DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn

    RegisterDllFromSection() failed.

--------------------
[07/03/23 12:04:53] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: dxupdate.cpp, line: 280, function: CSetup::InstallPlugIn

    DirectXUpdateInstallPlugIn() failed.

--------------------
[07/03/23 12:04:53] module: dsetup32(Mar 30 2011), file: setup.cpp, line: 1727, function: CSetup::SetupForDirectX

    InstallPlugIn() failed."
```

Comment: Which Win11 build are you on ?

Comment: What's the GPU? Did you try just manually installing Direct X from Microsoft's website?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was running Windows 11 Pro N, and clean installs (of the game, steam, and operating system) did not help at all. I finally decided to switch the version of windows. I then did a clean install of Windows 11 Pro (not the N version) and I am no longer having issues. So if you are using the N version of Windows (this version doesn't have the Windows Media Package included) try switching to the non-N, or vice versa. Hope this helps.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with it being a Windows N version.